# How to find sum of columns of foreign key on distinct value and group them

Tags: sql, postgresql

This is my orders table

```
id...order_date
1 ...2021-04-29
2 ...2021-04-29
3 ...2021-04-30
```

This is my order_products table

```
order_id...product_price
1       ...800
2       ...700
3       ...600
```

And this is the output I want to get

```
order_date...total_price
2021-04-29...1500
2021-04-30...600
```

order_id is foreign key in order_products table. I want to get the sum of prices in order_products table on distinct dates.
How can I query this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use GROUP BY on whatever you want to sum "on":

```sql
SELECT o.order_date, sum(p.product_price) AS total_price
FROM orders o, order_products p
WHERE o.orderid = p.orderid
GROUP BY o.order_date
```